# How to patch TuxLol on 14.04

Tags: command-line, 14.04, kernel

I installed League of Legends on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It installed and now I can play however the in game store dosent seem to work with the most recent patch. I read [How do I install tuxLoL on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469807/how-do-i-install-tuxlol-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts#new-answer?newreg=e8ddbfbe67194211bb286f6d3584157d) and did as it said however when i tried to patch it I got this error

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CommandLine, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'CommandLine, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CommandLine, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'CommandLine, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=de6f01bd326f8c32'

I ran the command

mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir /home/jsalex4/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot\ Games/League\ of\ Legends/

What can I do so that I can update TuxLol so I can use the in game league of legends store?

Comment: just trying to bump to the top

Comment: Try installing mono-complete and run the command again.

Edit: Yup, I was at the same place at you, install the mono-complete package, run the command and you can patch succesfully :)

Answer (score 0):

I download and install League of Legends almost everyday in my Ubuntu 14.04, so what you are asking is a routine for me.

**First step** download [Tuxlol](https://bitbucket.org/Xargoth/tuxlol/downloads/tuxlol-0.1-dd62ba8-bin.tar.gz),unzip, open folder, right click on tuxlol.exe, properties, copy file location.

**Secont step** open Terminal like a pro ctrl+alt+T, write cd, right click on Terminal, paste, enter.

**Third step** open Home directory, go to Play On Linux, then LeagueofLegends, drive_c, Riot Games, League of Legends and then right click on the folder Rads, then go to properties and final copy file location.

**Fourth step** go to [Tuxlol homepage](https://bitbucket.org/Xargoth/tuxlol/wiki/Home), copy text **mono tuxlol.exe patch --dir "** to your url or in a text file, paste your Rads file location, add an **"** at the end and copy all.

**Final step** Open your terminal (not a new one), **write sudo**, right click, paste,enter.

Job done. GG